# Form code is empty but the project compiles and the GUI is shown

Tags: vb.net, forms, user-interface

I have a project that has only one form, that is **Form1.vb**.

**When I double click this file to edit the controls with the toolbox, the file is opened, but it is empty.**

The strange thing is that when I compile and run the project, the GUI that I had created in this file (Form1.vb) is shown like it whas there, but as I said, the file is empty, so I can't edit the GUI.

How can I fix it?

A screenshot of the problem: 
[image: A screenshot of the problem]

For if you need, a screenshot of the project folder:
[image: A screenshot of the project folder]

Comment: You'd have to use a hex viewer to look at the content of the Form1.vb file.  Dollars to donuts all of your code has been replaces by binary zeros.  The kind of thing that happens when your machine crashes a few seconds after you saved the file.  That's why programmers use source control.  Don't use any?  You've learned an important lesson, it always needs to be learned the Hard Way.

Comment: @HansPassant : The version control is a good idea, but i dind't use it in this project. I think that the problem happened because I deleted the class Form1 from a ClassDiagram.cd. I thought that it only delete the reference to the diagram, but not the code. Yes, it is true, finally the important lessons needs to be learned in the hard way. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved.**

I can't get the code of Form1.vb, but I created a new form and copy the code of Form1.Designer.vb (this file was in my folder, and due to it the GUI was shown when I compile & run the project) to the form designer file of the new form. To did it, I opened the file with a text editor.

**It allowed me to edit the existing GUI preserving the properties of the controlls that I had created.**

Answer (score 1):

Your code file might be empty but the `.Designer.vb` file is not (from the screenshot it's seen that it's 15 KB).

The problem here is that your project seem to have lost the "link" between the designer file and the code file, and treats `Form1` as a normal class.

If you don't have a backup of your code file you will not be able to get your code back, but you can still make your form editable again by following these steps:

1. (This step is very important) Go into your project folder and **copy** `Form1.vb`, `Form1.Designer.vb` and `Form1.resx` to another folder.
2. Now that you have a copy of the files, go a head and delete Form1 from Visual Studio, and delete any left-over Form1 files from your project directory.
3. In Visual Studio right-click your project and go to `Add > Existing file...`. Browse to the folder where you copied the Form1 files in step 1, and select all three.
4. Press "Open", and the form should now be imported to your project as an editable form again.

---

**EDIT:**

Try opening the `Form1.vb` in Notepad and write:

```
Public Class Form1

End Class
```

in it, then redo the steps above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I tried it and the problem persist.

Comment: I've just solved it.  Your answer led me to the solution. 
See my answer if you want to read what I did. Thanks again.

Comment: @Pablo : I saw it. I've done the same before too, but usually the steps I wrote works and is the simpler solution. Believe me I've been through many kinds of data loss issues. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do first:
Click on "My Project" in Solution Explorer and check out under Application what your Startup form and Application type is.

Comment: Why would this be relevant?

Comment: Startup form: Form1.



Application type: Windows Forms Applications