# VB visual studio 2015 IDE: missing designer view of forms

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

When using the IDE, I notice that I can no longer open the designer view of certain forms. As seen in the screen shot attached, there is no "View Designer" in the pop-up menu. I didn't touch those files during this round of programming, so it should be the system that did the favor (or by my accident). I search online and although it is not a new question the solutions that I have found don't quite seem to work or maybe not intuitive enough for me to understand.

For example, one suggests to run "devenv" with either a skip or reset option. But I cannot find this program in my system (Windows 10 + Studio 2015). Other suggests to create new form and copy then delete old form, which I am not convinced and due to its manual complexity I would prefer something more simple if possible (what if it keeps happening in the future?).

Thank you very much for the help.

[image]

Follow the suggestion by Visual Vincent (i.e., delete all form files, re-add them, and add two lines in the form file), not quite work. Here is the screen shot.

Note "Form3", after re-adding, the file hierarchy becomes different.

[image]

Comment: Did you open the file? If you go to file, open file, and then select the file it should automatically open for you

Comment: Your project file is just broken, it no longer has the "form" icon.  Form1.vb still works and you also could open it.  Not mentioning that you could open Form1 just fine is rather pointless and doesn't help you get the answer you need btw.  Edit the .vbproj file with a text editor like notepad or use a backup copy from source control.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37154807/3740093

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been stated by Hans Passant, it is likely that your `ProjectName.vbproj` file has become damaged in some manner.  Most likely the `<DependentUpon>` tag was deleted from the entries of the constituent files of your Form3.

You can try to edit the project file yourself or you can try the following procedure.

1. In the Solution Explorer, select Form3.vb, Form3.designer.vb, and Form3.resx.
2. Right-Click on the selected file and click on "Exclude from Project".
3. Save the Project.
4. Close the Project.
5. Re-Open the Project.  At this point you should see Form3 with a normal tree structure except that it will be grayed out to indicate that it is not part of the project.
6. Right-Click on Form3 and select "Include in project".
7. Save the project.  All should be good at this point.

Edit:  In response to the comment about the Exclude From/Include In Project Solution Explorer options not existing in VS2015, I am adding this image.  Note that you can also select those items via the Project Menu dropdown.
[image]

Comment: Doesn't work, it doesn't have such clickable items like "Exclude from Project“ and "Include in project". Are you sure it is VS2015?

Comment: @user180574, While I can not guaranty that the overall procedure will solve your problem, the Exclude From/Include options do exist.  The only VS versions that I know of that does not offer those options is the older Express versions such as VB 2010 Express.

Comment: The "Exclude/Include" options do not always appear, at least in my case. I finally get the hierarchy right, the top is "Form3.vb", under it are "Form3.Designer...", "Form3.resx", "Form3", and yet still I cannot have the designer view. I don't want to spend more time on it. This is definitely one of a kind screwed-up IDE I ever use. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Much help for me today, thanks much! And VS 2015 does have exclude/include from project selections!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using C# but had the same problem. For me it turns out that I had declared other classes *before* my form class declaration ("public partial class MyForm: Form"). As soon as I moved those class declarations to the end of the file I could view the form designer again. Note:It is considered good practice to have such declarations in their own file.

Source:
[Fix removal of Windows Forms Form in project file by error, or intention, causing form Solution Explorer icon to change](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/33636058-fix-removal-of-windows-forms-subtype-form-subtyp)

Comment: That fixed it for me in my C# project.  It would be nice if VS would warn or give some kind of visual indication of the cause of this issue for the sake of the less competent programmers among us :-(