# why can't i open the design page of this project

Tags: vb.net, basic

I want to open the design page so that i can see what it looks like but i dont know how to help
enter image description here.
When  i right click on the form.vb there is no view designer option and i dont want to look at the designer tab because there is no GUI on it

[image: i want to look at the like GUI of this code but i dont know how]

sorry for being bad i just couldnt find the answer anywhere else

[image: this is the view i want (its photoshopped)]

Comment: Simply use `Shift + F7` from the `Form1.vb` code.

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VB visual studio 2015 IDE: missing designer view of forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37230322/vb-visual-studio-2015-ide-missing-designer-view-of-forms)

Comment: Have you tried creating a new project? Does it show the designer?

Answer (score 0):

In the Solution Explorer, the fourth button on the toolbar is a drop-down. Click it and select the item that is not currently checked. That should switch you from folder view to project view. You should then be able to open your form in the designer by double-clicking it.

Comment: i dont know which button you are talking about

Comment: theres no unchecked box in the drop down so you're not exactly helping but thanks

Comment: added another photo  thats what i want to see and when i do what you see there isnt an unchecked box

Comment: So what is in the drop-down? You're not exactly being helpful. That photoshopped image looks like you switched form folder view to project view but who knows, given that it's photoshopped. Clicking the button will probably just switch views anyway but clicking the drop-down should let you select. I shouldn't have to explain a toolbar. That fourth button on the toolbar is how you switch between views, one of the files in your project/solution folder and one of the items in your project/solution. You need the latter. If you can't work out how to get that then I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: i have no idea but whatever you tell me to do it wont let me do it, when i click the toolbar it just says no solutions found and the checked one thats already there. What i want to do i take a groupbox from this guys code and put it into my code which is why i wanted that other view so i could just copy and paste it, i cant copy it from the document outline because the document outline is also empty and i dont know how else to do it

Comment: Did you download a project from the internet with no solution, i.e. a VBPROJ file with no SLN file?

Comment: no the folder has a .sln and a .suo in it but the icon looks different to my other project so maybe that could be why?

Comment: Close VS and open the SLN file from Windows Explorer. What do you see then?